# Finding the most natural route between two points on a grid

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, artificial-intelligence

How can I find the most natural route (something a human might take) between two points assuming that I have an array of bytes, with each bit representing a fixed size square and indicating whether it is accessible or not? For example, assuming the array represents the following grid:[image]

Where grey squares cannot be crossed, I need an algorithm that would find the path indicated by orange squares, not that represented by brown squares.

Notice that, whilst the orange path is also the shortest, that is merely a bonus, not a requirement. I simply need to find the path with minimal changes in direction (achieving a decent balance between length and changes). Also, the algorithm must not require large amounts of memory, as it is to run on an embedded chip.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Rudy Velthuis, I haven't exactly explained what I meant by "natural". By natural, I mean a path that isn't too long and only requires the user to change direction a few times.

Comment: use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: @AndersCedronius Wouldn't that find me the most *efficient* route?

Comment: Please, define "the most natural route (something a human might take)" a little better.

Comment: @RandomUser that (Dijkstra) depends on the criteria you use for the algorithm - "expense" is defined by the way it is implemented.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I already have: "the path with minimal changes in direction"

Comment: Is that the only criterium? Nothing else? Because the brown route and the orange route both have 6 changes of direction, AFAICT. So that can not be the only criterium. I guess efficiency or distance also have something to do with it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Weirdly enough, that really is the only criterion. However, as I mentioned in my question, it would be nice to achieve a "decent balance between length and changes"

Comment: What's the difference between a grey and a white cell? I don't see any. If we can walk on all white cells, then it is possible to reach the goal with only 4 changes in direction, actually even 3 but this one isn't pretty.

Comment: If that is the only criterion, then why is the brown route wrong? FWIW, do we go from red to green, or from green to red? Assuming red to green: why, when going down after the second direction change and hitting the short gray wall, why doesn't the "human" go to the left (diagonally) and then down and then right? One less change of direction.

Comment: IOW, why does the "human" follow the lower diagonal gray wall, instead of just going down and then right? Only 5 changes of direction.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Well, I guess you were right about changes in direction not being the only criterion... Apparently, distance also matters a bit too.

Comment: Well if you use A* you say distance is the only thing that matters... and not the changes in direction, so the question is missleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A* is the way to go, but you should consider that it requires some hacks to produce "natural" paths.

Since your map allows diagonal movements the heuristic can be something like:

```
/* "Octile" heuristic */
int h(node n)
{
  int dx = abs(n.x - goal.x);
  int dy = abs(n.y - goal.y);

  if (dx > dy)
    return 14 * dy + 10 * (dx - dy);
  else
    return 14 * dx + 10 * (dy - dx);
}
```

Even with this heuristic you're running into ties: SW, SW, SW, W, W, W having the same cost as SW, W, SW, W, SW, W (which looks better).

There are some quick hacks to work around this problem (tie breaking).

They're described in [Amit's page](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html#heuristics-for-grid-maps) (which contains a lot of information and a [wonderful introduction to A*](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html)).

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for A* pathfinding. While it will have the side effect of finding the shortest path, it's also going to be natural looking. For a long time it was the gold standard in video games.

Here's an article on the algorithm. Note: you'll have to modify it slightly to allow for diagonal movement.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding

Answer (score 2):

Build a graph where each direction change is an edge.

Each cell is represented as 8 vertices. Vertical, horizontal, and diagonal edges are free (cost 0). Others have non-zero cost (or different costs for 45, 90 and 135 degree turns, if you want sharper turns to cost more). Connect adjacent cells in a natural way (N to S, W to E, SW to NE etc). Assign some cost to these edges too (or different costs for vertical/horizontal and diagonal edges, depending on how you define "path length").

Then use A* on the graph. By varying the costs you may tune the balance between "good-looking" and "short".